# Can a module be defined in multiple files?

Tags: ruby

Say I have a module `Test111`. Can I define the module in two files?

```
# file1.rb
module Test111
  # ...
end

# file2.rb
module Test111
  # ...
end
```

I am using module more like a namespace.

Comment: If that were not possible, you wouldn't be able to do monkey patching.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Defining a class/module (actually, classes are modules) twice reopens the class/module. Therefore, you can split it in as many files as you want. You just have to be careful about overwriting things and dependencies.